# Как найти максимальный элемент в динамическом массиве с помощью `std::max_element()`?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, динамические-массивы

Как найти максимальный элемент в динамическом массиве с помощью `std::max_element()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо знать размер массива.

Например, если вы создали динамически массив, как показано ниже.

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

size_t n = 10;

int *a = new int[n];

// заполнение значениями элементов массива

int *max = std::max_element( a, a + n );

if ( max != a + n )
{
    std::cout << "The maximum element is equal to " << *max << std::endl;
}
```

Или итератор можете объявить, используя спецификатор `auto`

```
 auto max = std::max_element( a, a + n );
```

В данном конкретном случае нет необходимости проверять, что максимальный элемент найден. Но в общем случае, когда вы априори не знаете, чему равно значение переменной `n`, то такую проверку лучше делать.

Чтобы определить позицию найденного элемента, вы, в принципе, можете просто вычесть начало массива из найденного итератора, как, например,

```
auto pos = max - a;
```

Однако с точки зрения стиля программирования лучше воспользоваться стандартной функцией `std::distance`, объявленной в заголовке `<iterator>`, Например,

```
#include <iterator>

//...

auto = std::distance( a, max );
```

Это делает ваш код более гибким, так как массив вы можете заменить, например, каким-нибудь стандартным контейнером, который не имеет итераторов прямого доступа, и код все равно будет работать.

Comment: `(max` скобка где-то потерялась или так и должно быть?

Comment: а n не надо умножать на sizeof(int)?

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо. Это опечатка.

Comment: @user227927 Нет, не надо, так как действует арифметика указателей. Выражение a + n указывает на место после последнего элемента массива, то есть тем самым задается диапазон.